# Want a Cell that Drops Down Below Activated Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

While writing a UITableView in iOS8 I've implemented swipe left/right gestures similar to that in Mail. I would now like to implement a cell that slides down below the cell which the user has just swiped left and tapped a button on. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the row that should slide out to the data model (`UITableViewDataSource`) of your `UITableView`, then tell the tableview section to update with an animation:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow this code but I don't think I'm implementing it correctly. 
Say I slide cell @ index 4 to the right w/ gestures to reveal a button (just like Mail, like 'Flag'). Once I tap 'Flag' I would like a new cell to be made and then slide down out from underneath the cell @ index 4, inserting a new cell @ index 5 with an animation where it slides down.

Comment: Add the new cell to your data source (I don't know how you implemented that, so it's hard to say what you need to do exactly). Then call the code above (replace section 0 with the section you changed) and you should get the animation. Please let me know what problems you have with that.